# No result from Facebook likes query for a long URL

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I have two pages, `/a/` and `/a/b/c/` with Facebook *like* buttons. When I query Facebook, I can get the number of likes for the first page but not for second. Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/http://ubuntu.local:8000/a/ =>

```
{
   "id": "http://ubuntu.local:8000/a/",
   "shares": 1
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/http://ubuntu.local:8000/a/b/c/ =>

```
{
   "id": "http://ubuntu.local:8000/a/b/c/"
}
```

What should I do to get the result for a longer URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a known non-working URL, I would suggest trying to URL Encode your URL. Also, what do you get when you try "linting" the URL that doesn't work?  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: Here's the correct graph location for that url (based upon what the linter told me)  http://graph.facebook.com/10150423699047496 and here is the other graph url: https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.mallpages.com/a/b/c

Comment: i put meta in <header>,[link](graph.facebook.com/http://www.mallpages.com/a/b/c/) gives share;
[link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mallpages.com%2Fscarborough-town-centre%2Fbanana-republic) gives proper info,
 but [link](https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.mallpages.com/scarborough-town-centre/banana-republic/) still doesn't give shares - how can i get it?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your question is.  is it the a/b/c link?

Comment: Thank you for ideas! After i fixed meta property for LIKE button in <head> tag i can receive likes for long urls with graph api.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint helps me to see what was the problem.